# How to specify user ID when creating a user in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I specify my own user ID when inserting a new user in wordpress?

Looking at this page here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user

It doesn't give me an option to specify the user ID of the user I want to insert into wordpress.

How would I be able to specify the User ID then?

Comment: you dont, why do you want to?

Comment: Maybe when importing users from another system.

Answer (score 1):

The user id ( `ID` ) in wordpress is auto-increment field, you cant specify it while adding new user, if you add it then update will be done matching the user id rather new insert, like:

```
$user_id = 10;
$somevar = 'test';
wp_insert_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'user_dat' => $somevar) ) ;
```

Since `ID` is provided here, the user id with value 1 will be updated, if matching `ID` is found.

Comment: So we can create the user, then update it's ID afterwards? I didn't truly understand the example, sorry.

Comment: again, why would you want to, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @user27899 as Dagon asked, why would you want to update user's ID, can you clear your requirement

Comment: I need to integrate a forum with wordpress. So when I create a user in wordpress, I want it to have the same ID as the user in the other plat form did. Which is why I want to specify the user ID.

Comment: Thats not the proper way to integrate two systems, you should use a user meta field to hold the foreign ID.

Comment: @doublesharp, that makes more sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

According with Wordpress documentation, if a user ID is pass to the wp_insert_user() function, it will try to modify the user with that ID if exists, but a new user won't be created. You sould store the facebook ID as user_meta.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, I think it helps to solve this problem. But the set ID must be an integer value.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `$table_name`(`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_url`, `user_status`, `display_name` ) VALUES (4545343,'$user_name','$pass','$fullName','$user_email','$time','$user_id','$url','0','$user_id')";
```